# How can I use ec2.py and localhost at the same time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

How can I use the ec2.py to get a dynamic list of ec2 hosts and also use localhost as a host.  I have googled over and over and can't seem to find a good solution.  I have come across some close answers but all seem to require breaking your tasks down into two separate playbooks that can't be run at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was trying to solve a similar issue.

I had a bunch of hosts which accepted connections from the Ansible host. For security reasons the Ansible host was not allowed to connect to itself. However, I needed to run the Common play on all host.

I specified all hosts, excluded the Ansible host, and then added localhost:

```
- name: Common
  hosts: "tag_name_*:!tag_name_ansible:localhost"
  roles:
    - common
```

Adding localhost worked fine even when using the EC2 inventory script. I am using Ansible 1.7 with an up-to-date EC2 inventory script.

Answer (score 27):

This isn't the only solution—valid suggestions have been made—but what I almost always end up doing when using the EC2 inventory plugin is exploiting an Ansible feature that I think many people don't know about: you can use a *directory* as inventory.

Ansible looks for executables and flat files in a directory and merges their results. This is very helpful because you can use a flat file to make nice aliases for dynamic groups, and add localhost in there, possibly setting some variables for it.

```
$ tree inventory/staging
inventory/staging
├── base
├── ec2.ini
├── ec2.py
└── group_vars -> ../group_vars
```

An excerpt of the file `base` looks like this:

```
[localhost]
# I need to tell Ansible which Python on my system has boto for AWS
127.0.0.1 ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python

# The EC2 plugin will populate these groups, but we need to add empty entries
# here to make aliases for them below.
[tag_Stage_staging]
[tag_Role_webserver]

[staging:children]
tag_Stage_staging

[webservers:children]
tag_Role_webserver
```

You then just point to the directory for inventory:

```
$ ansible -i inventory/staging webservers -m ec2_facts
# OR
$ export ANSIBLE_HOSTS=inventory/staging
$ ansible webservers -m ec2_facts
```

Comment: Finally!  Thank you SO MUCH for posting this.  I just looked for a way to create aliases of dynamic groups but none of the Ansible docs mention this 'empty group' trick!  This really needs to be made more widely known!  I never would have thought to create a group of the same name as the tag in my static inventory file (and expect it to get populated via a dynamic script such as ec2.py).

Comment: I don't know if something has changed in Ansible lately, but I can't make this (elegant) solution work - none of my plays referencing the aliased names are able to resolve the `tag_Role_xxx` group names, as though ec2.py is not being called. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're having trouble getting this to work, edit `ec2.py` to add a line that prints to stderr (standard error output) or creates a file, so you can see when it runs.  The reference to inventory directory `inventory/staging` should cause it to run.   Also, try doing `python ec2.py --list` to check it works standalone.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can achieve what you want to do using the `-l` parameter of the ansible-playbook command.

We do something similar and the ansible-playbook command we use looks similar to this

```
ansible-playbook -l tag_foo_bar:localhost -U username -i ec2.py playbook.yml
```

The part after the `-l` is just an ansible *pattern* (http://docs.ansible.com/intro_patterns.html) which means "limit execution to all instances with tag 'foo=bar' AND the localhost host". The important part is the colon which just means "and".

Comment: Thanks this solved my issue, I was kicking off `ansible-playbook` in a script that limited by EC2 tag, but also needed to run a localhost action first. This worked in Ansible 1, but Ansible 2 changed it. I'm now adding localhost to my limit (eg. `--limit=tag_env_test:localhost`)

Answer (score 0):

@ches, this is not going to work if you have multiple environments with instances tagged with Role=webserver. Your command:

```
$ ansible -i inventory/staging webservers -m ec2_facts
```

will pick up every single instance tagged as webserver and not only those ones that belong to staging environment. If you want to pick up only the web servers from staging you will still need to run:

```
$ ansible 'staging:&webservers' -i inventory/staging -m ec2_facts
```

except if I'm missing something here.

Comment: This should probably be a comment rather than an answer, but: yes, you're correct if you're using one AWS account for multiple environments, which you probably are if you have a "staging" tag for instance. My example could have been better. Sometimes the pattern you point out (addressing all hosts with a given tag, across all environments) is rather useful, though it's confusing/error-prone if the inventory is called `staging` but still needs an additional limit specified to truly scope it. There are several options, depending on the setup you prefer:

Comment: 1.) Use `--limit staging`, a little nicer-looking for CLI than the host selection syntax you showed, but still confusing/error-prone as aforementioned if your inventory is already called `staging`. Useful for a "master inventory" though. 2.) I believe you can define the `webservers` alias as `tag_Role_webserver:&staging` in `inventory/staging/base`, but I can't test at the moment. This is probably clearest for this particular setup approach. 3.) Use multiple AWS accounts for environments; the highest human error isolation, and with consolidated billing, not as annoying as it may sound.